# Is my homebrew "Charger" fighter archetype balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, archetype, mounted-combat, homebrew-review

I was looking at the mounted fighter subclass and realized that none of them have anything to do with mounted combat. So I decided to make my own subclass and was wondering if I could get some good objective feedback to better determine whether it's over/under powered, needs tweaking, or is in a good place compared to other fighter archetypes.

**Is my homebrew "Charger" fighter archetype balanced?**

---

> ## [Charger](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LKqi9vHvIhIi8wHbWWUijVDHoszNXSrqK38RbPzpzDw/edit?usp=sharing)
>
> The charger is made for mounted combat. Unlike the other mounted archetypes which are made for “mounted combat”, the charger is made for use on a mount in combat.
>
> #### Bonus Proficiency
>
> At 3rd level, choose one of the following skills to become proficient in: Animal Handling, Perception, Survival, Persuasion, or Insight.
>
> #### Bind
>
> At 3rd level, you bind to the spirit of a mount to gain the following benefits:
>
> - When you receive healing, your mount is healed by the same amount.
> - You can summon your mount once per long rest (even if it died), with all its stuff.
>
> #### Maintenance Expert
>
> At 3rd level, the cost of all mount-related expenses (stabling, feed, saddles, mounts, etc...) is halved.
>
> #### Negate Reaction
>
> At 7th level, you don’t trigger reactions after moving 20 feet in a straight line, and enemies have disadvantage on reactions against you if you move 10 feet in a straight line. If you start your movement fleeing from a enemy within 5 feet of you, your mount can make an attack. The target must succeed on a DC 5 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone, or if your mount has a charge ability the DC is increased by 5.
>
> #### Continuous Charge
>
> At 7th level, you can attack while moving once every 10 feet, and you can charge through an enemy letting your mount attack. The target must succeed on a DC 5 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone letting your mount attack again, or if your mount has a charge ability the DC is increased by 10. This does not count towards the aforementioned 10 feet.
>
> #### Bound Feet
>
> At 10th level, you choose between 5 different feats: Mounted Combat, Charger, Healer, Alert, or Mobile. Mobile applies to your mount and to ranged weapons.
>
> #### Focus Attack
>
> At 15th level, you can make two attacks as one combining the damage and the attack bonus.
>
> #### Legendary Action
>
> At 18th level, you get one legendary action.

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer: No.

Nearly every ability you provide is overpowered.

**Bind** - This Find Steed that doesn't require a spells lot to create and can be done at will. While not every spell applies to it, healing does.

**Maintenance Expert** - This is a pretty underpowered 3rd level ability and will likely only become an issue at tables that require mundane maintenance.

**Negate Reaction** - This is basically giving you a 'free' disengage and free reaction attack. That's quite a lot and is overpowered.

**Continuous Charge** - THis is granting you additional attacks that you normally wouldn't have  and greatly boosts your action economy beyond the baseline.

**Focus Attack** - This is also incredibly powerful. Allowing you to stack your bonuses into a single attack basically turns this into a near-guaranteed hit (1s aside) with massive damage.

**Legendary Action** - No PC build gets anything like this. Not even Level 20 capstones approach this.

### Homebrew thoughts

It may make some sense to look at the Ranger Beastmaser or revised Beast conclave to give you some ideas on a PC class that has a strong connection to an animal. It'll give you some guidance as to how to structure a homebrew and to make equivalences in your development. But in general, I'd recommend staying away from things that aren't generally available to players at all - like legendary actions.

Comment: Not only does no player character class get a legendary action, but this doesn't even define what it can be used to *do*.